# How to store and restore the exact type of a type-erased object?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, type-erasure

I'm sure there's a name for what I'm looking for, I just don't know it (and if I did, I'd probably find the answer already). Basically, I want to implement my own lightweight version of `std::function` for sports. I want to initialize it with a lambda, and later invoke it. I can wrap the lambda with my template wrapper class, nothing to it:

```
struct CInvokableAbstract {
   virtual ~CInvokableAbstract() = default;
};

template <class InvokableObject>
struct CInvokableBasic : public CInvokableAbstract
{
    CInvokableBasic(InvokableObject&& target) : _invokable(std::move(target)) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    typename std::result_of<decltype(&InvokableObject::operator())(Args...)>::type operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        return _invokable(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    InvokableObject _invokable;
};
```

Now I can make my class that's semantically similar to `std::function`, but how can I store the exact type of the lambda in order to convert the type-erased object back to its original concrete type?

```
struct CInvokableDeferred
{
    template <class InvokableObject>
    CInvokableDeferred(InvokableObject&& target) noexcept : _invokable(std::make_unique<CInvokableBasic<InvokableObject>>(std::move(target))) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        // How can I know the original concrete type to cast this to?
        static_cast<???>(_invokable.get())->(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<CInvokableAbstract> _invokable;
};
```

I can't think of any template trickery that could do that, yet we know it's possible (unless `std::function` uses some compiler built-ins, or otherwise is implemented internally in the compiler rather than being normal C++ code).

Note that I'm using a compiler that doesn't have full C++17 support, so I can't use e. g. `auto`-deduced return type.

Comment: I realized that my (now deleted) answer wasn't the most elegant solution. I don't think I'm going to rewrite it, see @r3musn0x's suggestion below.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: they say you can't take a function pointer to a lambda that captures (which makes sense, but pity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rewrite your base class as follows:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
class CInvokableAbstract {
   virtual ~CInvokableAbstract() = default;
   virtual Ret operator()(Args... args) = 0;
};
```

This will make your base class dependent on the signature (which it has to be in order to be usable) and provide the actual interface for the invocable object.

Note that this part of code actually has nothing to do with type-erase, it's just plain old dynamic polymorphism. It's the combination of static (`CInvokableBasic` template) and dynamic (`CInvokableAbstract` interface) polymorphisms that make type-erasure possible.

Comment: I see what you did there, very simple indeed. Still, I wonder if there is any way to solve my original question as presented?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, I thought this answers your original question, please clarify.

Comment: It answers my original intention, but is there a way to avoid making `CInvokableAbstract` a template?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, the most important thing is that `CInvokableAbstract` and `CInvokableDeferred` are not dependent on the type of the object they are wrapping, thus implementing type-erasure. On the other hand they are dependent on the function signature because it's a part of their interface regardless of the underlying object type. You can only get rid of those template parameters (`Ret` and `Args`) by hardcoding a specific signature. Otherwise if two callable objects where wrapped in the same type regardless of the signature, how would you know how to invoke them?